# Java Question Linked List objects

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following piece of code :
Essentially the number of methods should remain the same as in the code and I need to extract a string from an element of the linkedlist of Objects of type emp_struct.. How do I do it?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class a1 {

    static LinkedList l1;
    private emp_struct input() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        emp_struct obj = new emp_struct();
        obj.emp_id = br.readLine();
        obj.name =  br.readLine();
        obj.salary = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        obj.dept = br.readLine();
        try{
            search(obj);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            obj = input();
        }
        return obj;

    }

    boolean search(emp_struct obj)
    {
        int lastIndex = l1.lastIndexOf(l1);
        int begIndex = 0;
        for(begIndex =0;begIndex<lastIndex;begIndex++)
        {
            Object chkCase = l1.get(begIndex);
            String chk = chkCase.getEmpID();
            if(chk.equals(obj.emp_id));
                throw new DuplicateEntryException("Duplicate entry found");

        }           
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        l1 = new LinkedList();
    }
}

class DuplicateEntryException extends Exception {
    String detail;
    DuplicateEntryException(String a)
    {
        detail = a;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "User Defined Exception : "+detail;
    }
}

class emp_struct {
    public String emp_id;
    public String name;
    public double salary;
    public String dept;

    public String getEmpID()
    {
        return emp_id;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return emp_id+"\t"+name+"\t"+salary+"\t"+dept;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or real-world code?

Comment: hope it's a homework..looks a bit messy

Comment: this was supposed to be a homework and i was experimenting while writing the code and i am stuck overhere in the search method specifically

Comment: What's the original assignment? It may help to pull this back and get you back on a clean path.

Comment: what's with the recursive call to input, and the throwing of the exception? looks very messy...

Answer (score 0):

In your search method, if you find the value, you're throwing an exception. If you don't find the value, you return `true`. This doesn't seem like the best approach.

If you find the value, shouldn't you return `true`, then if it makes it through the array without finding it, shouldn't you return `false`?

Comment: agreed but the homework says u have to use a user defind exception so i was forced to do it that way however I still need to extract the string from the object at specified index of the linked list which is not part of my homework

Comment: Sounds like you want to change the return value of your method to return a String

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
Object chkCase = l1.get(begIndex);
```

should be

```
emp_struct chkCase = (emp_struct)l1.get(begIndex);
```

among other things...